# How to reproduce the behavior of a VCL TComboBox in FMX?

Tags: firemonkey, c++builder, c++builder-10.3-rio

I want to reproduce the behavior of a VCL TComboBox in FMX, for that, i suppose that i have to use a TComboEdit, but i don't know to reproduce the exact ehavior, especially auto deleting when going back on the field or the autocomplete.

Comment: *Which* behavior are you trying to reproduce exactly? Please be more specific.

Comment: The autocomplete is the main issue, especially since i don't know how to select only the autocomplete prevision.